# Git Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit

Tags: git, git-pull, git-status

На локальной машине делаю

```
$ git push origin master
```

После чего на удаленном

```
$ git status
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git pull origin master

remote: Counting objects: 10, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 10 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (10/10), done.
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 2df9bf3..2447f2a
Fast-forward

$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Почему появился коммит? Что с ним делать?

Comment: скорее всего произошел мердж. git log и смотрите, что там произошло.

Comment: Да, произошли некоторые изменения в файлах. Меня они устраивают, что делать с коммитом? Или как правильно производить изменения на удаленном сервере?

Comment: запушить, если устраивают и удалить (reset) если не нужны.

Comment: А зачем ее пушить? Я ее только с удаленного репозитория забрал..

Comment: @KoVadim, всё гораздо проще. см. мой ответ.

Comment: У меня обычно так происходит, когда по ошибки делаю коммит в master ветку при этом master для меня закрыт. Тогда я перехожу на свою ветку (либо создаю новую) и пушу там коммит. При всё этом, когда заново перехожу на мастер, то там пишем именно то, что вы написали вверху `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit` и `(use "git push" to publish your local commits)`. Так как там нет для меня ничего важно, то я просто делаю сброс кеша **`git reset --hard origin/master`**. Это меня выручает, может это вам поможет.

Answer (score 2):

преднапоминание: ветка в *git* — это лишь «плавающий» указатель на коммит.

---

команда:

```
$ git pull origin master
```

не обновила (и не должна была обновлять) указатель `origin/master`, только указатель `master`, «передвинув» его на один (в вашем случае) коммит «вперёд».

вот команда *status* и говорит вам о том, что ваш текущий указатель `master` находится «впереди» (ahead) от указателя `origin/master`.

чтобы «исправить упущение», достаточно выполнить, например:

```
 $ git fetch
 From url-репозитория
   xxxxxxx..yyyyyyy  master     -> origin/master
```

в приведённом выводе видно, что как раз и обновляется ссылка `origin/master`.

после этого команда *status* не должна сообщать вам о расхождении между указателями.

---

а вообще, непонятно, зачем вы пишете `git pull origin master`, учитывая, что текущая ветка у вас и так явно связана («set upstream») с веткой `master` в репозитории `origin`. достаточно ведь просто:

```
$ git pull
```

и не будет у вас описанных в вопросе расхождений.

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Откатитесь до прежнего коммита: 
`git --force 2df9bf3` 
после сделайте пул, коммит и пуш в этой поочередности.

Comment: git --force 2df9bf3 - не понятна эта запись. Действия делаются на удаленном сервере? А это не будет повторением тех же действий, которые я делал до этого?

Comment: @Ptica вы пока что не имеете доступа до удаленного репозитория, так как на вашем локальнем есть конфликты  в коммитах. 
если вам нужно откатить коммит на удаленном репозиторие добавьте до записи: `git push --force 2df9bf3`

Answer (score 0):

У меня обычно так происходит, когда по ошибки делаю комит в master ветку при этом master для меня закрыт. Тогда я перехожу на свою ветку (либо создаю новую) и пушу там коммит. При всё этом, когда заново перехожу на мастер, то там пишем именно то, что вы написали вверху 
`On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)`

 Так как там нет для меня ничего важно, а то, что было важно уже залито в новую ветку, то я просто делаю сброс кеша **`git reset --hard origin/master`**. Теперь после команды `git status` показывает `On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean`
 Это команда меня выручает, может и вам поможет.